# How can I use "nprogreess"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have installed `npm install nprogress` succesfully in my project, but when I try to refresh my page then the console shows me a message:

```
hot-dev-client.js:182 [Fast Refresh] done
hot-dev-client.js:196 [Fast Refresh] rebuilding
hot-dev-client.js:182 [Fast Refresh] done
```

But inside my page it does not display any animation for the refresh. I have checked many times with slow network on network tab, but it still is same problem.

I have imported `nprogress.min.css` like this: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.2.0/nprogress.min.css`

And in my header page I have tried code like this:

`import NProgress from "nprogress";`

`import { useRouter, Router } from "next/router";`

```
Router.onRouteChangeStart = (url) => NProgress.start();
Router.onRouteChangeComplete = (url) => NProgress.done();
Router.onRouteChangeError = (url) => NProgress.done();
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think events must be listened to like this:

```js
Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => NProgress.done());
```

[Official doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents)